# Which module called my DLL exported function?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, c++14, dllexport

#### Background

I'm developing a C++ windows DLL module that exports a single function

```
__declspec(dllexport) void Run()
```

#### Motivation

I would like to implement some sort of accessing rights to my function. I wish to prevent unauthorized modules from activating my DLL proc.

I don't need a robust/bullet proof mechanism. I only like to "defend" this proc from other modules running under my own app.

#### Approach

Get the calling module name and decide based on the name if access is granted.

#### Question

1. Would this approach suffice?
2. if so, how do I get the name of the calling module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if so, how do I get the name of the calling module?

1. get return address by call [_ReturnAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64ez38eh.aspx)
2. get base address of the image that contains this return address -
   [RtlPcToFileHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680603(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. finally call [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) function

so code can be like this

```
HMODULE hmod;
if (RtlPcToFileHeader(_ReturnAddress(), (void**)&hmod))
{
    WCHAR sz[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetModuleFileName(hmod, sz, MAX_PATH))
    {
        DbgPrint("%p %S\n", hmod, sz);
    }
}
```

---

about - are this work in *XP* ? yes, but with one note. *_ReturnAddress* is *CL* intrinsic - so not depended from os version (for say gcc exist  *__builtin_return_address (0)* ) [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) also very old api function and exist in win2000, xp, everywhere. about [RtlPcToFileHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680603(v=vs.85).aspx)
- it exported (and implemented) in *ntdll.dll* in all windows versions from *xp* to latest. also begin from *win2003* it also exported from *kernel32.dll* but implementation here - simply *jump* to *ntdll.RtlPcToFileHeader* - so if want use this on xp also - link with *ntdll.lib* and place it before *kernel32.lib* in libs order or can get it it runtime by `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll"), "RtlPcToFileHeader");`

or even if somebody afraid that *RtlPcToFileHeader* will be removed from *ntdll* (this is of course no) can use this 
    `GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(g_xp ? L"ntdll" : L"kernel32"), "RtlPcToFileHeader");`

Comment: Nice. is this impl. supported by XP?

Comment: @idanshmu - yes, this work in xp too. only `RtlPcToFileHeader` is exported from *ntdll.dll* in Xp

Comment: An alternative would be using `GetModuleHandleEx` with the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` flag. Also exists since XP.